How to work with Websockets using a ATWINC1500 and STM32Duino
I was learning about web servers and home automation from a YouTube tutorial online, the author started teaching about Websockets and he was using Libraries for the ESP32. I could not find any Websocket Library/example for my ATWINC1500 breakout board that I bought from Adafruit.
I tried going to Adafruit's tutorial page on the ATWINC1500 Breakout Board, But they didn't provide clear documentation/examples besides from running a "webclientexample". I tried checking out WiFi101 Library as the tutorial page used that library for the example. However, There was nothing about websockets there.
I tried searching on the internet for any libraries that provide websocket example for my ATWINC1500. Not much luck there, most of all the websocket libraries are only ESP32/ESP related.  I tried searching YouTube for a tutorial. There was literally nothing on my module.
